# Gdata youtube upload failedWithStatus:400

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, youtube, gdata

i have a small app in which i use gdata to upload a video to youtube. Everytime I try, I get the following error: "serviceBase: objectFetcher: failedWithStatus:400 data:GData`InvalidRequestUriException`Missing or invalid username."

I tried using my youtube accout, or my gmail accout and none worked. Any help would be appreciated.

here is the code:

```
NSString *devKey = DEVELOPER_KEY;

GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
[service setYouTubeDeveloperKey:devKey];

NSString *username = @".........@gmail.com";
NSString *clientID = CLIENT_ID;

NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username
                                                         clientID:clientID];

// load the file data

NSString  *videoPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/output.mp4"];

//    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YouTubeTest" ofType:@"m4v"]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoPath];
NSString *filename = [videoPath lastPathComponent];

// gather all the metadata needed for the mediaGroup
NSString *titleStr = [titleTextField text];
GDataMediaTitle *title = [GDataMediaTitle textConstructWithString:titleStr];

NSString *categoryStr = [mCategoryField text];
GDataMediaCategory *category = [GDataMediaCategory mediaCategoryWithString:categoryStr];
[category setScheme:kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory];

NSString *descStr = [mDescriptionField text];
GDataMediaDescription *desc = [GDataMediaDescription textConstructWithString:descStr];

NSString *keywordsStr = [mKeywordsField text];
GDataMediaKeywords *keywords = [GDataMediaKeywords keywordsWithString:keywordsStr];

BOOL isPrivate = mIsPrivate;

GDataYouTubeMediaGroup *mediaGroup = [GDataYouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup];
[mediaGroup setMediaTitle:title];
[mediaGroup setMediaDescription:desc];
[mediaGroup addMediaCategory:category];
[mediaGroup setMediaKeywords:keywords];
[mediaGroup setIsPrivate:isPrivate];


NSString *mimeType = [GDataUtilities MIMETypeForFileAtPath:videoPath defaultMIMEType:@"video/mp4"];

// create the upload entry with the mediaGroup and the file data
GDataEntryYouTubeUpload *entry;

NSLog(@"%@", mimeType);

entry = [GDataEntryYouTubeUpload uploadEntryWithMediaGroup:mediaGroup
                                                      data:data
                                                  MIMEType:mimeType
                                                      slug:filename];

SEL progressSel = @selector(ticket:hasDeliveredByteCount:ofTotalByteCount:);
[service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:progressSel];

GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                  forFeedURL:url
                                    delegate:self
                           didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];

[self setUploadTicket:ticket];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Error code 400 is a bad request "Invalid request URI or header, or unsupported nonstandard parameter." Which basicly means you have misformatted your request. [HTTP Status Codes](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/reference.html#HTTPStatusCodes) Link to explain all error codes.

Could you post the code you are using to upload the video?

EDIT:
Can you upload using the [YouTube Sample](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExamples%2FYouTubeSample)?

If this works fine it will prove you devkey is working fine. It will also show that it is a problem with on of these lines:

```
NSString *username = @".........@gmail.com";
NSString *clientID = CLIENT_ID;

NSURL *url = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeUploadURLForUserID:username
                                                     clientID:clientID];

NSString  *videoPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/output.mp4"];
```

Again if the sample YouTube sample is working then the problem is either

1. The client hasn't been authenticated with your devkey.
   or
2. The videoPath isn't the correct location.

Comment: sorry for the delay ... i cannot upload with the Youtube Sample ... same error.